# echo inside a for loop lists files matching the output pattern

Tags: bash, shell, glob

I have a problem with the following for loop:

```
X="*back* OLD"
for P in $X
do
echo "-$P"
done
```

I need it to output just:

```
-*back*
-OLD
```

However, it lists all files in the current directory matching the `*back*` pattern. For example it gives the following:

```
-backup.bkp
-backup_new.bkp
-backup_X
-OLD
```

How to force it to output the exact pattern?

Comment: You could use `set -f` to disable pathname expansion completely.

Comment: for this particular case and data: `printf -- '-%s\n' $X`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array, as unquoted parameter expansions are still subject to globbing.

```
 X=( "*back*" OLD )
 for P in "${X[@]}"; do
     printf '%s\n' "$P"
 done
```

(Use `printf`, as `echo` could try to interpret an argument as an option, for example, if you had `n` in the value of `X`.)

Comment: Thanks @chepner. This works well. However, I cannot quote the pattern `*back*` because these patterns are read from a file to a variable like this: `X=\`cat patterns\``. Could you suggest a solution for this problem?

Comment: Use `readarray -t X < patterns`, assuming the intent is to treat each line of the file as a separate pattern.

Comment: The quotes in the assignment to `X` shown is only to prevent globbing in the shell assignment; you don't need to "inject" quotes into  a file that just has `*back*` as a line.

Comment: Thanks @chepner. This works well. Could you tell me why we use `${X[@]}` not just `${X}` or `$X`?

Comment: When quoted, it expands not to a single word, but a sequence of separate words, each of which is treated as if it had been quoted individually. (That is, `"${X[@]}"` is equivalent to `"${X[0]}" "${X[1]}" ...`.)

Answer (score 1):

Use `set -o noglob` before your loop and `set +o noglob` after to disable and enable globbing.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html) you could read in the string as a [Here String](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html).

To iterate over the items, you could turn them into lines using [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) and read them linewise using `read`. In order to be able to put a `-` sign as the first character, use `printf` instead of `echo`.

```sh
X="*back* OLD"
while read -r x
do printf -- '-%s\n' "$x"
done <<< "${X/ /$'\n'}"
```

Another way could be to use `tr` to transform the string into lines, then use `paste` with the `-` sign as delimiter and "nothing" from `/dev/null` as first column.

```sh
X="*back* OLD"
tr ' ' '\n' <<< "$X" | paste -d- /dev/null -
```

Both should output:

```
-*back*
-OLD
```

Comment: `echo` might be *a* problem, but it's not *the* problem being asked about.